# Codeigniter - Failing to load config

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my code, According to the [user guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html), I write this code (In a controller)

```
$this->config->load('countries_config.php');
```

But unfortunately, get this PHP error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Countries::$config
>
> Filename: controllers/Countries.php
>
> Line Number: 12

Any idea why I can't use the config?

`Countries` extends `CI_Controller`

Comment: Did you check the file location in folder structure?

Comment: application/config/countries_config.php

Comment: try without the .php file extension...should work

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#manual-loading

Answer (score 1):

> To load one of your custom config files you will use the following
>   function within the controller that needs it:
>
> $this->config->load('filename');
>
> Where filename is the name of your config file, without the .php file
>   extension.

without .php extensions

try this

```
$this->config->load('countries_config');
```

Comment: @Amit show you `countries_config.php` I fink error in file

Comment: One liner: `$config['test'] = true;`

Answer (score 0):

what is counteries_config.php is this controller,model or view file 
$this->config->load('filename');

Comment: It is a config file

Comment: then use $this->config->load('filename');

Comment: This is what I am using

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem occured because I was trying to load the config file before doing `parent::_construct();`

Fixed by doing it after